# Need to put this object into an array, how?

Tags: javascript

I need convert following in the EXACT format shown below with javascript, could you please suggest how to achieve this

from: `{"healthy":true,"unhealthy_reasons":[]}`
to: `[{"healthy":true,"unhealthy_reasons":[]}]`

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your sample data where a string is being converted into an array. The only difference between the "from" and the "to" is that the "from" object has been placed into an array, which is trivially `[from]`

Comment: sorry for the typo... yes indeed the object need to be placed inside array

Comment: If your source object is in a variable called `from`, then `let to = [from];` is all you need.

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
let data = '{"healthy":true,"unhealthy_reasons":[]}';
let parsed = JSON.parse(data);
//TO get an array
console.log([parsed])
//TO get a string
console.log(JSON.stringify([parsed]))
```

Comment: That does not produce `[{"healthy":true,"unhealthy_reasons":[]}]`

Comment: OP has now clarified that this question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Also this still produces the wrong outcome...

Comment: indeed it does not provide output as [{"healthy":true,"unhealthy_reasons":[]}]

Answer (score 0):

If that's all you need to do, you can just wrap array brackets around the variable that contains the object:

```
let initialObject = {"healthy":true,"unhealthy_reasons":[]};
let arrayedObject = [initialObject];
```

But I'm wondering if there's more to this. If this is actually part of a more complicated task, just add that to your question and you'll get a more complete answer.